# ignore na data from merging multiple columns into one

Tags: dataframe, merge, multiple-columns, na, fillna

[Pic1](https://ibb.co/QHH90RC)
[Pic2](https://ibb.co/MZtG53r)

```py
pic 1:my first code

North["NEWLotNo2"]=NORTH.apply(lambda x:"%s %s,%s,%s"%(x["LotNo"],x["Sect1"],x["Subset1"],x["set2"]),axis=1)
```

i found result be:[ 520D, Nan, Nan]

pic 2.then, i added

```py
North=North.fillna(" ")
```

but the result be: [520D, , ,]

i need the perfect result should be [520D]
if there is nan data, it shouldn't be shown and no comma as well.